# Sending email from Bash fails with no error message

Tags: macos, bash, email

I am trying to send an email from my terminal (bash). I did:

```
echo "text" | mail -vs "subject"  "myself@address.com"
```

The verbose flag returns

```
Mail Delivery Status Report will be mailed to <Me>
```

But neither the `Mail Delivery Status Report` nor the email is received in my inbox. The `Mail Delivery Status Report` seems to be save in the file `/var/mail/Me`. Here is the last report I received:

```
--EAB82C90F6D.1445818910/Remis-MacBook-Pro.local
Content-Description: Delivery report
Content-Type: message/delivery-status

Reporting-MTA: dns; Remis-MacBook-Pro.local
X-Postfix-Queue-ID: EAB82C90F6D
X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; remi@Remis-MacBook-Pro.local
Arrival-Date: Sun, 25 Oct 2015 17:21:49 -0700 (PDT)

Final-Recipient: rfc822; myself@address.com
Action: delayed
Status: 4.4.1
Diagnostic-Code: X-Postfix; delivery temporarily suspended: connect to
    alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.219.26]:25: Connection refused

--EAB82C90F6D.1445818910/Remis-MacBook-Pro.local
Content-Description: Message Headers
Content-Type: text/rfc822-headers

Return-Path: <remi@Remis-MacBook-Pro.local>
Received: by Remis-MacBook-Pro.local (Postfix, from userid 501)
        id EAB82C90F6D; Sun, 25 Oct 2015 17:21:49 -0700 (PDT)
To: myself@address.com
Message-Id: <20151026002149.EAB82C90F6D@Remis-MacBook-Pro.local>
Date: Sun, 25 Oct 2015 17:21:49 -0700 (PDT)
From: remi@Remis-MacBook-Pro.local (Remi)

--EAB82C90F6D.1445818910/Remis-MacBook-Pro.local--
```

What is going wrong?

---

I am on Mac OSX El Capitano Version 10.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mixing [these instructions](http://www.anujgakhar.com/2011/12/09/using-macosx-lion-command-line-mail-with-gmail-as-smtp/) and [these instructions](https://gist.github.com/larrybotha/6009971#comment-1325112) I added,

```
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = plain
```

to `/etc/postfix/main.cf`

I also created `/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd` and wrote

```
[smtp.gmail.com]:587 username@gmail.com:password
```

in it. I then ran

```
sudo chmod 600 /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
sudo postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
sudo launchctl stop org.postfix.master
sudo launchctl start org.postfix.master
```

and changed my google account settings to allow "less secure apps" (see instructions [here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255)). And it worked!